# How to store strings of text files for later use in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, jfilechooser

Please forgive me, I'm relatively new to Java.

Basically I'm wanting to get some string for a text file for later use after selecting the file through a filechooser.

This is a snippet of the code that I have written so far.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == openButton){
        returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            //read file
            try{
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                    if(currentLine.startsWith(organismId)){
                   // if(Character.isDigit(currentLine.charAt(7))){
                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                }}
            } catch (Exception error){
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have a variable (organismId) which is determined by user input through a GUI. From this I can print out the lines which begin with the chosen String variable. However this isn't exactly what I want to achieve. I want to be able to gather the text that is present on the next line, until a character ">" is reached.

I then want to be able to get an average character length for the text for each different organismId (i.e. >ggo and >hba).

I.e. an example of what the text file may look like is as follows:

>ggo

This is an example sentence

>ggo

This is another example sentence

>ggo

This is a further example sentence which is extremely long and can go onto more than one line as is demonstrated here

>hba

This is a sentence with a different organismId

I hope that all of this makes sense and any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet should be a solution to your problem. `printLines` is used to start printing lines after your organism has been found. The while loop continues round and if another organism is not found, then the line is printed. But when a new organism is reached (denoted by `>` I believe), then `printLines` is set back to `false`.

```
ArrayList<String> organisms = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean printLines = false;
StringBuilder organism = new StringBuilder();
while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (printLines) {
        if (currentLine.startsWith(">")) {
            // We have reached the next organism, so stop printing
            printLines = false;
            // Add the current organism to our collection
            organisms.add(organism.toString());
            // Clear the StringBuilder, ready for the next organism
            organism.setLength(0)
        }
        else
        {
            // We are still printing the current organism
            organism.append(currentLine);
        }
    }

    if(currentLine.startsWith(organismId)) {
        // Print this line, and start printing all lines after this
        organism.append(currentLine);
        printLines = true;
    }
}
```

Let me know below if you have any queries or comments.

*Edit* As requested in the comments, have edited to add values into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply and sorry for the delayed response. Whether it's me not inserting the code in the correct place i'm not sure. With the snippet of code above it still prints just the current line. However I want to print what is on the next line until a ">" is present, not including the current line. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay I've managed to fix it.. the final line should be `printLines = true` as opposed to false but the rest of the code was great! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Another question. If I wanted to put all text from each organism (I.e after the `>ggo` but before the next `>` ) onto the same line, how would I go about this? I want to eventually put each into an ArrayList however currently when I attempt to do this it put each line into the array list, and not the entire String for each organism. Thanks

Comment: I've actually had a much better idea. You can read your entire file into 1 string using `String organismString = new Scanner(new File("yourfile")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();` and then you can use `String[] organismArray = organismString.split('>')` From there you can use `ArrayList<String> organisms = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(oranismArray));` to turn the array into your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. An issue however with your suggestion is that I'll be working with files which are extremely large (92000 lines plus). Will this not considerably slow down the process? Also is it possible to use Scanner when I'm using a filechooser to select my file? I'm having errors occur when I try to do so.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my solution with a simpler way to save your results. You could use a `Scanner` with `userDelimiter(">")` just as easy, using `scanner.next()` to populate your `ArrayList`, but there seems to be a discussion ongoing about whether `BufferedReader` or `Scanner` is best. I'd say just stick with what you know for now and follow my answer.

Comment: Okay I've managed to get my code to work as I would like now :) However there is one problem I've encountered. I've realised that the final organism isn't being appended to the ArrayList and I can't quite understand why that's the case. I understand that when a `>` is reached it adds the current organism to the ArrayList but I've tried several things including `if (currentLine.startsWith(">") || currentLine.isEmpty())` but nothing I do seems to work properly. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: If you have one final `organisms.add(organism.toString())` after the while loop, that should add the remaining, good spot again Matt!